# Why does my while loop only run once?

Tags: python

I want to make this loop run more than once but it will only run once and then stop. What am I doing wrong?

```
a = 0
Let = input("Enter a sentence to decrypt : ")
Num = 0
b = 0
while b < 26 :
    Num = Num + 1
    num = int(Num)
    while a < len(Let) :
        if  ord(Let[a]) > 96 and ord(Let[a]) < 123 and ord(Let[a]) + Num > 96 and ord(Let[a]) + Num < 123 : 
            print(chr(ord(Let[a]) + Num))
        elif ord(Let[a]) > 64 and ord(Let[a]) < 91 and ord(Let[a]) + Num > 64 and ord(Let[a]) + Num < 91 : 
            print(chr(ord(Let[a]) + Num))
        elif ord(Let[a]) > 96 and ord(Let[a]) < 123 and ord(Let[a]) + Num >= 123 :
            while ord(Let[a]) + num >= 123 :
                    num = Num - 26
            print(chr(ord(Let[a]) + num))
        elif ord(Let[a]) > 64 and ord(Let[a]) < 91 and ord(Let[a]) + Num >= 91 :
            while ord(Let[a]) + num >= 91 :
                    num = Num - 26
            print(chr(ord(Let[a]) + num))
        a = a + 1
    b = b + 1
```

Comment: How are you verifying it runs only once?

Comment: Just a side note, b += 1 is the same as b = b + 1.

Comment: Just tested - it seems to work fine

Comment: I have this in the IDLE and when I run it in the shell, I enter something short for example cffq. What I expect to happen is it to give me a long list of answers such as dggr and beep but what actually happens is it prints dggr and stops

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: It's definitely running the "b" loop 26 times, whether its doing what you want is a different issue than the original question.

Comment: `a` keeps getting increased until it's equal to `len(Let)`, then `b` gets increased until it's equal to `26`.

Comment: I want it to run 26 times but when I run it, what I get is only one output instead of 26.

Comment: Looks like its supposed to be some kind of decryption function for text encrypted as other letters at my best guess...

Comment: Yes that's exactly it but it doesn't seem to work on my computer

Comment: It offsets them by 1, so gdkkn is hello

Comment: Yes but when I run it with ehhs in hopes of getting a bunch of possibilities including beep it will print fiit and then stop.

Comment: You need to reset a to 0, I'll post a answer.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"a" is not being reset to 0 in the "b" loop:

```
Let = input("Enter a sentence to decrypt : ")
Num = 0
b = 0
while b < 26 :
    Num = Num + 1
    num = int(Num)
    a = 0
    out = ""
    while a < len(Let) :
        if  ord(Let[a]) > 96 and ord(Let[a]) < 123 and ord(Let[a]) + Num > 96 and ord(Let[a]) + Num < 123 : 
            out += (chr(ord(Let[a]) + Num))
        elif ord(Let[a]) > 64 and ord(Let[a]) < 91 and ord(Let[a]) + Num > 64 and ord(Let[a]) + Num < 91 : 
            out += (chr(ord(Let[a]) + Num))
        elif ord(Let[a]) > 96 and ord(Let[a]) < 123 and ord(Let[a]) + Num >= 123 :
            while ord(Let[a]) + num >= 123 :
                    num = Num - 26
            out += (chr(ord(Let[a]) + num))
        elif ord(Let[a]) > 64 and ord(Let[a]) < 91 and ord(Let[a]) + Num >= 91 :
            while ord(Let[a]) + num >= 91 :
                    num = Num - 26
            out += (chr(ord(Let[a]) + num))
        a = a + 1
    print(out)
    b = b + 1
```

Changed to a "for" loop:

```
Let = input("Enter a sentence to decrypt : ")
Num = 0
b = 0
while b < 26 :
    Num = Num + 1
    num = int(Num)
    out = ""
    for a in Let:
        if  ord(a) > 96 and ord(a) < 123 and ord(a) + Num > 96 and ord(a) + Num < 123 : 
            out += (chr(ord(a) + Num))
        elif ord(a) > 64 and ord(a) < 91 and ord(a) + Num > 64 and ord(a) + Num < 91 : 
            out += (chr(ord(a) + Num))
        elif ord(a) > 96 and ord(a) < 123 and ord(a) + Num >= 123 :
            while ord(a) + num >= 123 :
                    num = Num - 26
            out += (chr(ord(a) + num))
        elif ord(a) > 64 and ord(a) < 91 and ord(a) + Num >= 91 :
            while ord(a) + num >= 91 :
                    num = Num - 26
            out += (chr(ord(a) + num))
    print(out)
    b += 1
```

Comment: Or, better yet, use a `for` loop to iterate through all letters

Comment: There, it's a for loop now, no need to increment "a".